# Kafka Consumer group - No of partition - No of replication

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Trying to Understand the relationship between replication factor and Consumer group . Example : Number of partition  = 2 Number of replication = 3 Number consumers in consumer group = 4 . In this case ,

1. How many consumer will receive the message ?
2. How This replication will impact the number of consumer to receive .

Answer (score 6):

- For your first question, since you have two partitions in your example, only 2 of the 4 consumers will actually get data.  The other two consumers will not have any partitions assigned to them, because there aren't any partitions left *for that consumer group*.  If you had a different consumer group, then those consumers would still be assigned partitions.
- Additionally, in this case, you mention there's only a single message coming through.  Depending on which partition it's assigned to, the message will *only* be sent to that partition.  So in this case, only *one* of the four consumers will get the message, the one that had that partition assigned to it.
- As for your second question, replication factor configuration in Kafka doesn't impact the number of messages consumers receive. Replication, as far as consumers and producers are concerned, is an **internal kafka cluster detail** that they don't need to worry about.  As long as they're producing/consuming to/from the leader of the partition, that's all they need to know.  A topic could have replication factor 2, and another one could have replication factor 10, and they would both behave identically to producers and consumers.

There's a few more details in the official Kafka documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer

Answer (score 1):

To give some additional details on the *replication factor*, it doesn't have any relation whatsoever to the number of consumers receiving messages from the topic. Replication serves only one major purpose, and that is **High Availability**. So, let's say you have 3 brokers in a cluster, and for a topic *my-topic* you've set replication factor as 2. Now, if at-most one broker goes down at some point of time, you'd still be okay, as the messages are replicated in another broker for the topic.